# How to import Balistica lib (.vala) into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, vala

does anyone know how to import this ( https://github.com/steveno/balistica ) lib into Android Studio ? How I understand it is written on Vala language and I have never worked with it. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to achieve, since Vala code can't be compiled for Android easily. But if you are adventurous, you can try to follow what is said [in this article](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/25), event if it is a bit old, and I'm not sure it will be still working.

Once you cross-compiled the library, just add the `.so` file in your project and try something like that:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // This will load libmylibrary.so
    static { System.loadLibrary("mylibrary"); }

    // "Import" the foo method from the library
    private static native void foo ();
}
```

Vala automatically changes the names to camel case and the methods signatures to make it work in C, so you'll probably have to read the `.h`
file to know how to call each method.